# Data no Framework Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou tentando criar um campo Date no codeligniter para o usuário informar a Data, criei um arquivo helper com o código para data (na verdade usei um código que foi de ajuda a outra pergunta neste site), mas não estou conseguindo usar. Tenho algumas dúvidas quanto ao código, 1º Após carregar o helper no meu controller estou carregando o método criado para formatar data em uma variavel no qual chamo ela na view, Estou fazendo da forma certa? 2º quando eu realizo teste a data que eu digitei no formulario, dou um vardump para testar o que me retorna, e retorna NULL. 3º Qual é a sintaxe da função nativa do codeigniter _parse_form_attribute, o manual do codeigniter esta fora tem uns dias e não estou conseguindo dar continuidade a meu projeto.

```
//HELPER

    if ( ! function_exists('form_common')){
    function form_common($type = 'text', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        $defaults = array('type' => $type, 'name' => (( ! is_array($data)) ? $data : ''), 'value' => $value);

        return "<input "._parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults).$extra." />";
    }
}

    if ( ! function_exists('form_date')){
    function form_date($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        return form_common($type = 'date', $data = '', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}

//CONTROLLER REALIZEI TESTE PARA VER O QUE ESTA ME RETORNANDO APÓS DIGITAR A DATA E CLICAR NO BOTÃO, MAS O RESULTADO É NULL

    if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'Abrir Agenda >>'){
            $data = $this->input->post('data');
            echo 'A data Informada é '.$data;
            var_dump($data);
        }

//VIEW

    echo form_date('data', 'data');
```

COMO FAÇO PARA ADICIONAR UM NOME A ESTE CAMPO DE DATA E CHAMA-LO NOVAMENTE PARA ATRIBUIR SEU VALOR A UMA VARIAVEL.

Comment: A minha pergunta esta descrita da forma correta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja com atenção sua função form_date, ao chamar a função form_common vc está atribuindo valores na variáveis ao invés de passar os valores recebidos para a função, a forma correta seria:

```
if ( ! function_exists('form_date')){
function form_date($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
{
    return form_common('date', $data, $value, $extra);
}
```

Comment: Obrigada já achei a solução.
if ( ! function_exists('form_date'))
{
    function form_date($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
      return form_common($type = 'date', $data = 'data', $value = '', $extra = '');
    }
}